# Chrome Dev Tools: body element cover others when using elements selection tool

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, document-body

Chrome Dev Tools: body element cover others when using elements selection tool on other small elements.

When I am trying to inspect .h1 div "Ready house projects" text as element - i can expect only body element with 
cursor(only right part of element in snippet). What makes body element working in this way by hiding other elements?

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
/*FONTS */
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Beresta';
 src: url('../fonts/Beresta-Normal.eot');
 src: url('../fonts/Beresta-Normal.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/Beresta-Normal.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/Beresta-Normal.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/Beresta-Normal.svg#Beresta-Normal') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-stretch: normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Medieval';
 src: url('../fonts/Medieval-Normal.eot');
 src: url('../fonts/Medieval-Normal.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/Medieval-Normal.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/Medieval-Normal.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/Medieval-Normal.svg#Medieval-Normal') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-stretch: normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Kelsonsans';
 src: url('../fonts/Kelsonsans-Bold.eot');
 src: url('../fonts/Kelsonsans-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/Kelsonsans-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/Kelsonsans-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/Kelsonsans-Bold.svg#Kelsonsans-Bold') format('svg');
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: normal;
 font-stretch: normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Opensans';
 src: url('../fonts/Opensans-Regular.eot');
 src: url('../fonts/Opensans-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/Opensans-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/Opensans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/Opensans-Regular.svg#Opensans-Regular') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-stretch: normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Kelsonsans';
 src: url('../fonts/Kelsonsans-Regular.eot');
 src: url('../fonts/Kelsonsans-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/Kelsonsans-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/Kelsonsans-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/Kelsonsans-Regular.svg#Kelsonsans-Regular') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-stretch: normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Als-Rubl';
 src: url('../fonts/Als-Rubl.eot');
 src: url('../fonts/Als-Rubl.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/Als-Rubl.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/Als-Rubl.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/Als-Rubl.svg#Als-Rubl') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-stretch: normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Verdana-Bold';
 src: url('../fonts/Verdana-Bold.eot');
 src: url('../fonts/Verdana-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/Verdana-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/Verdana-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/Verdana-Bold.svg#Verdana-Bold') format('svg');
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: normal;
 font-stretch: normal;
}

/*END FONTS */
.fluid-container {
 min-width: 1000px;
}
.call_btn{
 vertical-align: top;
 background-color: #f19f00;
 float: right;
 width: 188px;
 height: 39px;
 margin-left: 18px;
 margin-top: 6px;
}
.call_btn:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
}
div.call_btn_sign{
 color: white;
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 400;
 border-bottom: 2px dotted white;
 width: 137px;
 display: block;
 margin-left: 25px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}
.container {
 min-width: 1000px;
 max-width: 1200px;
}
.none{
 display: none;
}

/* STRIKETHROUGH */
 .strikethrough {
   position: relative;
 }
 .strikethrough:before {
   position: absolute;
   content: "";
   left: -4%;
   top: 40%;
   right: -4%;
   border-top: 1px solid;
   border-color: inherit;
   color: black;

   -webkit-transform:rotate(-11deg);
   -moz-transform:rotate(-11deg);
   -ms-transform:rotate(-11deg);
   -o-transform:rotate(-11deg);
   transform:rotate(-11deg);
}
/* END STRIKETHROUGH  */

/* RUBL */
 span.rubl {
    font-family: 'Als-Rubl'!important;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 100;
}
/* END RUBL */

/* HEADER */
.logo {
 background: url(../images/logo.png) center center no-repeat;
 width: 85px;
 height: 75px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.contacts {
 display: inline-block;
}
.sprite_phone:before {
 background: url(../images/phone_sprite.png) center center no-repeat;
 content: " ";
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: -10px 0 0 -25px;
}
.upper-head {
 display: block;
 height: 115px;
 background-color: white;
}
div.sprite_phone a {
 color: #192d37;
 font-family: "Kelsonsans";
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 700;
 padding-left: 5px;
}
div.email{
 margin-top: 6px;
}
.email a {
 color: #192d37;
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.upper-head .container {
 padding-top: 18px;
 margin-bottom: 21px;
}
.left-up-h {
 float: left;
}
.right-up-h {
 float: right;
 margin-top: 18px;
}
.l-u-h_text {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 18px;
}
.h2 {
 font-family: "Beresta";
 color: #192d37;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin-top: 8px;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.h3 {
 color: #686d6f;
 font-family: "Medieval";
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin-top: 8px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.header-logo {
 background: url(../images/header_panoram.png) center center no-repeat;
 height: 500px;
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
}
.discounts {
 margin-top: 280px;
 color: white;
}
.discounts-box {
 display: block;
 height: 60px;
 border: 4px solid #E9B707;
 font-size: 30px;
 width: 360px;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 1;
 margin-left: 65px;
 padding-top: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}
.present_sprite_box {
 display: block;
 background-color: #E9B707;
 content: "";
 border-radius: 2px;
 float: left;
 height: 60px;
 width: 60px;
 position: relative;
}
.present_sprite {
 background: url(../images/gift_icon.png) center center no-repeat;
 width: 35px;
 height: 40px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 12px;
}
.discounts-box_backgr {
 display: block;
 width: 360px;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: black;
 top: 0px;
 z-index: -1;
 opacity: 0.4;
 margin-left: 65px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
}
div.discounts-box{
 color:white;
}

 /* GIFT WINDOW */
  div.present_window{
   height:325px;
   width: 550px;
   position:absolute;
   top:-170px;
   background:white url(../images/form_background.png) center bottom no-repeat;
   left:0px;
  }
  div.container_pres{
   margin-left: 30px;
   margin-top: 38px;
   height: 209px;
   width: 490px;
  }
  div.presText{
   width: 488px;
   margin-left: 1px;
  }
  div.presText span{
   font-family: "Kelsonsans";
  }
  div.present_window input[type="text"]{
   width: 268px;
   height: 46px;
   background-color: #fafafa;
   border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
   box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   color: #686d6f;
   font-family: "Opensans";
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: 400;
   padding-left: 12px;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   border-top-left-radius: 3px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  }

  input.yellow-button{
   font-weight: 400;
   height: 46px;
   width: 220px;
   background-color: #eab600;
   border: none;
   font-family: Verdana;
   font-size: 16px;
   float:right;
   color: #192d37;
   text-decoration: underline;
  }
  .presText h2{
   color: #192d37;
   font-family: "KelsonSans";
   margin-top: 0px;
   font-size: 33px;
   font-weight: 400;
  }
  .presText p{
   font-family: "Verdana";
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: 400;
   line-height: 18px;
  }
  p.first_p_text_present{
   color: #686d6f;
   margin-top: 26px;
  }
  p.second_p_text_present{
   color: #192d37;
   margin-top: 18px;
  }
  div.inputboxes_pres{
   margin-top: 31px;
  }
 /* END GIFT WINDOW */

/* END HEADER */

/* HEADER_BOTTOM */
.header-logo_bottom {
 background: url(../images/menu_line.png) center center no-repeat;
 height: 10px;
}

/* END HEADER_BOTTOM */

/* MAIN MENU */
.main_menu {
 background: url(../images/menu_sprite.png) center center no-repeat;
 height: 50px;
 width: auto;
 margin-top: -30px;
 z-index: 1;;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
.main_menu ol {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.main_menu li {
 display: inline-block;
}
.main_menu a {
 font-family: Verdana;
 position: relative;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 12px 18px;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 500;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
}
.main_menu a:hover {
 color: #E9B707;
}
a#to_customer:after{
 content: "";
 background: url(../images/menu_sprite_dropdown.png) center center no-repeat;
 display: block;
 width: 6px;
 height:5px;
 float: right;
 position: absolute;
 left: 111px;
 top: 21px;
}
.to_customer_submenu{
 content: "";
 height: 150px;
 width: 260px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 54px;
 left: 665px;
 text-align: left;
 background: url(../images/dropdown_menu_sprite.png) center center no-repeat;
}
.to_customer_submenu li:first-child a{
 padding:12px 18px;
}
.to_customer_submenu a{
 padding: 9px 18px;
}
/* END MAIN MENU */
/* READY PROJECTS*/
.ready_projects_back{
 width: auto;
 z-index: -1;
 margin-top: -31px;
 position: relative;
 background: url(../images/bg_ready_projects.png);
 height: 738px;

}
.ready_projects_back .h1{
 font-family: KelsonSans;
 font-size: 60px;
 color: #192d37;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin-top: 60px;
 text-align: center;
}
.bold_ready_projects{
 color: #eab600;
 font-weight: 700;
}
.ready_projects_back .h3{
 color: #686d6f;
 font-family: KelsonSans;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-align: center;
}
.ready_projects_back .proj_box .h3{
 color: #192d37;
 font-family: KelsonSans;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-bottom: 10px;; 
}
.proj_box{
 background-color: white;
 width: 320px;
 height: 450px;
 
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 5px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 position: relative;
}
.discount_proj div.discount_sign{
 position: absolute; 
 background: url(../images/%.png) center center no-repeat;
 margin-left: 15px;
 height: 51px;
 width: 40px;
}
div.proj_box.discount_proj{
 border: 4px solid #eab600;
}
div.proj_box.discount_proj input{
 background-color: #eab600;
 color: black;
}
.project-boxes{
 height: 478px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: grey;
 margin-top: 30px;
}
div.proj_inbox{;
 display: block;
 margin-top: 16px;;
 margin-left: 18px;;
 margin-right: 18px;;
 position: relative;;
}
.proj_inbox .h5{
 color: #192d37;
 font-family: KelsonSans;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 35px;
 margin-bottom: 11px;
}
.proj_inbox .h4{
 color: #686d6f;
 font-family: KelsonSans;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: -4px;
}
.proj_inbox .h1{
 font-family: KelsonSans;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;

}
.proj_inbox p{
 color: #686d6f;
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 18px;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin-top: 8px;
}

.proj_inbox p b{
}
.proj_inbox img{
 width: 100%;
}

div.proj_box input{
 text-decoration: none;
 height: 40px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 5px;
 background-color: #192d37;
 color:white;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

.barcode{
    white-space:pre; 
}
.discount_proj .proj_btn_line{
 left: 58px;
 top: 386px;
 border-color: black;
 
}

.proj_btn_line{
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
 width: 160px;
 opacity: 1;
 top:390px;
 left:62px;
 z-index: 1;
}
.line{
 content: "";
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 0.2;
}

/*NAVIGATION*/
 .proj_box_nav{
 text-align: right;

 }
 .go_catalog{
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #192d37;
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 18px;
 text-decoration: underline;
 }
 .catal_arr_left{

 }
 .catal_arr_right{

 }
/*END NAVIGATION*/

/* END READY PROJECTS*/
```

```html
 
 <body>  
  <!--HEADER-->
  <div class="fluid-container upper-head">
   <div class="container">
    <a href="index.html" class="left-up-h">
     <div class="logo"></div>
     <div class="l-u-h_text">
      <div class="h2">Пестовские срубы</div>
      <div class="h3">У нас всегда хорошие цены!</div>
     </div>
    </a>
    <div class="right-up-h">
     <div class="contacts">
      <div class="sprite_phone"><a>8 (981) 260-50-50</a></div>
      <div class="email"><a href="#">pestovskiesrubi@gmail.com</a></div>
     </div>
     <a href="#" class="call_btn">
      <div class="call_btn_sign">Заказать звонок</div></a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="fluid-container header-logo">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="discounts">
      <a href="#">
       <div class="present_sprite_box">
        <div class="present_sprite">
        </div>
        <div class="discounts-box">
         Узнайте о наши акциях
         <div class="discounts-box_backgr"></div>
         <div class="present_window none">
          <div class="container_pres">
           <div class="presText">
            <h2><b>Ваш подарок</b> готов к отправке!</h2>
            <p class="first_p_text_present">Всем, кто заключит договор на строительство дома или бани – индивидуальный подарок.</p>
            <p class="second_p_text_present">Узнайте подробности, оставьте телефон и мы перезвоним вам!</p>
            <div class="inputboxes_pres">
             <input type="text" name="phone_for_gift" placeholder="Ваш телефон"><input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="yellow-button">
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="fluid-container header-logo_bottom">
   </div>
   <div class="container main_menu">
    <ol>
     <li><a href="#">Срубы домов</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Срубы бань</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Фотогалерея</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Где строим</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="to_customer">Заказчику</a>
     <div class="to_customer_submenu none">
      <ol>
       <li><a href="#">Способы оплаты</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Доставка материалов до участка</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Строительство в кредит</a></li>
      </ol>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Схема работы</a></li>
   </ol>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--END HEADER-->
 
 <!--READY PROJECTS BACK-->
 <div class="fluid-container ready_projects_back">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="h1"><span class="bold_ready_projects">Ready</span> house projects</div>
   <div class="h3">Срок постройки по готовому проекту меньше недели!</div>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="project-boxes">
     <div class="proj_box discount_proj">
      <div class="discount_sign"></div>
      <div class="proj_inbox">
       <div class="h5">Проект Д-47</div>
       <img src="images/project_box.png">
       <div class="h4">Цена от: <span class="strikethrough">1 500 000</span></div>
       <div class="h3">1 300 000 <span class="rubl">a</span></div>
       <div class="line"></div>
       <span class="barcode"><p>Площадь: <b>120 м<sup>2</sup>  /</b>   Размер: <b>6х9 м</b></p></span>
       <div class="proj_btn_line"></div>
       <input type="submit" value="Посмотреть проект" class="yellow-button">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="proj_box">
      <div class="proj_inbox">
       <div class="h5">Проект Д-47</div>
       <img src="images/project_box.png">
       <div class="h4">Цена от: <span class="strikethrough">1 500 000</span></div>
       <div class="h3">1 300 000 <span class="rubl">a</span></div>
       <div class="line"></div>
       <span class="barcode"><p>Площадь: <b>120 м<sup>2</sup>  /</b>   Размер: <b>6х9 м</b></p></span>
       <div class="proj_btn_line"></div>
       <input type="submit" value="Посмотреть проект" class="yellow-button"> 
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="proj_box">
      <div class="proj_inbox">
       <div class="h5">Проект Д-47</div>
       <img src="images/project_box.png">
       <div class="h4">Цена от: <span class="strikethrough">1 500 000</span></div>
       <div class="h3">1 300 000 <span class="rubl">a</span></div>
       <div class="line"></div>
       <span class="barcode"><p>Площадь: <b>120 м<sup>2</sup>  /</b>   Размер: <b>6х9 м</b></p></span>
       <div class="proj_btn_line"></div>
       <input type="submit" value="Посмотреть проект" class="yellow-button">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="proj_box_nav">
      <div class="go_catalog">Перейти в каталог</div>
      <div class="catal_arr_left"></div>
      <div class="catal_arr_right"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--END READY PROJECTS BACK-->
 <!--PROJECTS_QUALITY-->
 <div class="projecs_quality">
  <div class="h2">Пустовские срубы - качество от производителя</div>
  <div class="achiev_blocks">
   <div class="ach_blk"></div>
   <div class="ach_blk"></div>
   <div class="ach_blk"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="qual_overwrite">Любой здравомыслящий человек мечтает о красивом, уютном доме в живописном местечке за городом, который можно использовать для сезонного или постоянного проживания. Стоит уточнить, что какими бы прекрасными ни были загородные дома на вторичном рынке жилья, они не могут в полной мере соответствовать всем требованиям будущего домовладельца. Заказав строительство деревянных каркасных домов под ключ в Ярославле у нас, Вы станете владельцем идеального строения, которое устроит Вас по всем параметрам. Вы лично сможете выбрать проект будущего дома и, если необходимо, принять непосредственное участие в процессе его корректировки.</div>
  <div class="h2">Как мы строим срубы</div>
  <div class="qual_plan_img"></div>
  <div class="h2">Выгодно для вас</div>
  <div class="benefits_boxes">
   <div class="benefit_box"></div>
   <div class="benefit_box"></div>
   <div class="benefit_box"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--END PROJECTS QUALITY-->
 
 <!--EASY WORK-->
 <div class="fluid-container easy-work">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="h2">С нами легко работать!</div>
   <div class="easy_boxes">
    <div class="easy_box"></div>
    <div class="easy_box"></div>
    <div class="easy_box"></div>
    <div class="easy_box"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="easy_box"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--END EASY WORK-->
 <!--FOOTER-->
 <div class="container">
  <div class="footer">
   <div class="footer-1"></div>
   <div class="footer-2"></div>
   <div class="footer-3"></div>
   <div class="footer-4"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--END FOOTER-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `z-index: -1` on your `ready_projects_back` class, which is pushing the `div` element below the other layers in the stack. The `body` element covers the whole page, so setting the [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to anything less than that, will prevent you from inspecting it with the tool.